# The effect of Acronis image restore on Windows 7 password expirations

Tags: windows-7, windows, passwords, group-policy

I have a question about how user account password expiration works within Windows 7.  I have been able to fine some explanations online about individual aspects of my situation, but nothing which covers how the different aspects work together.

**Situation:**
I'm using an Acronis image to prepare multiple Windows 7 laptops with identical (strict) security restrictions.

One such restriction is a Group Policy "maximum password age" setting of 60 days.

```
Within the Local Group Policy Editor: Computer Configuration->Windows Settings->
Security Settings->Account Policies->Password Policy->Maximum Password Age
```

However, the image itself is a few years old, and the "net user" command shows that the admin account's password was last changed in the year 2013.

The "net user" command also shows that the admin account "Password Expires" date is "Never".

**Question:** Is the password expiration of "Never", as reported by the "net user" command, accurate, or is it superseded by the "60 days" in the local group policy?

If the "60 days" is accurate, how does Windows determine when the password should expire, if the "Password last set" value is carried over from the (two year old) image loaded by Acronis?

Comment: Group policy superseds all local policies. Enforcement requires connection to the domain obviously

Comment: I think that might be part of my confusion; the policy is configured on each individual laptop, but they are not connected to one unifying domain.  Each one will be on its own LAN of other devices and no other device can "enforce" policy changes on it...we have to login via VNC, or locally, to make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

A *network* password can be enforced easily because it is enforced by a separate network server.

However, when a full laptop image is restored, **if** the local time were to be set back and **if** it is off the network, then any **old local password** would be restored and **would still be valid**, whatever group or local policy is set.

To get around that issue, either:

1. Ensure that the user does not have access to a local account, so that all login is through the network.

Or

2. Supervise the restoration and, at that time, ensure that any local account password has expired.